# Do-while loop using C

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf

I'm using a while loop per below:

```
do {

    scanf("%c", &turnChoice);

    if (turnChoice == 'r')
    {
        invalidSelection = false;
    }

    else if (turnChoice == 'h')
    {
        invalidSelection = false;
    }

    else
    {
        printf("Invalid input.\n");
    }

} while (invalidSelection == true);
```

However, before stopping for the user input, it runs the full loop once (so it displays "Invalid input" and then asks the user for a letter). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Most likely the code before this left a character in the input buffer.

Comment: no character's are inputed before (i just declare the variable; no initialization)

Comment: That's a do...while loop. Always executes once.  You want a while loop, evaluates before looping. http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson3.html

Comment: why don't you just print out turnChoice?

Comment: @DomB So this is the first input in your program? No keys are hit before this? There's no code that runs prior to this that does any input? I find that very hard to believe.

Comment: well...the things that are inputed are for different variables. turnChoice is only touched at the scanf statement above.

Comment: @DomB So there's your problem. That prior code is leaving a character in the input buffer that this code is reading. Since it's probably not an "h" or "r" (most likely a newline/enter), this code tells you that it's invalid.

Comment: And the lesson to learn is this: Don't write code that reads characters if you want to read lines. Just don't. Code what you want, not something else.

Comment: what is data type of  **turnChoice**?

Comment: NEVER compare a value to TRUE.   so this line: `} while (invalidSelection == true);`  should simply be: `} while (invalidSelection);`  and before the loop insert the statement: `invalidSelection = !FALSE;`

Comment: The `scanf()` for a character needs to get by any left over white space.  always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  So this line: `scanf("%c", &turnChoice);`   should be: `if( 1 != scanf(" %c", &turnChoice) ) {//handle error}`  Notice the leading space in the format string.

Answer (score 5):

My guess is that you have some input *before* the code you show, some input that you end with a newline, right?

The problem here is that the newline is still in the input-buffer when you call `scanf` to read a character, so that newline is what you read and get.

There is a very simple "trick" to tell `scanf` to read *and discard* leading white-space (like newlines), and that is to prepend a single space to the format string, so try e.g.

```
scanf(" %c", &turnChoice);
//     ^
//     |
// Note space here
```

Comment: That's a good point. I missed that... See @DavidSchwartz comment.

Answer (score 1):

After take char input, we need to take '\n' char which is giver by pressing the enter button

```
    char turnChoice;
    bool invalidSelection = true;
    do {

    scanf("%c", &turnChoice);// if you want to give leading space then use scanf(" %c",&turnChoice);
    getchar();
    if (turnChoice == 'r')
    {
        invalidSelection = false;
    }

    else if (turnChoice == 'h')
    {
        invalidSelection = false;
    }

    else
    {
        printf("Invalid input.\n");
    }

} while (invalidSelection == true);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help, when you scanf put "%*c" after your first character to ignore the enter key that you hit after entering the input. Code is as follows:

```
do {

scanf("%c%*c", &turnChoice);

if (turnChoice == 'r')
{
    invalidSelection = false;
}

else if (turnChoice == 'h')
{
    invalidSelection = false;
}

else
{
    printf("Invalid input.\n");
}

} while (invalidSelection == true);
```